# query to get last years data missing dec data

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query to get previous years data like

```
vsqlstr := 'select name, enrollement_dt,case_name, dept, city, state, zip from enrollement where ';
    vsqlstr :=vsqlstr ||' enrollement_dt <= to_date(''12''||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1), ''MMYYYY'')  ';
```

DB has foll. records:

```
Name Enrollement_Dt Case_name dept city state zip
ABS  2019-AUG-16    TGH       ENG   NY   NY    46378   
BCD  2019-DEC-31    THG       SCI   VA   VA    76534
EFG  2019-DEC-31    TGY       HIS   WA   WA    96534 
HIJ  2019-DEC-31    YUI       MATH  PA   PA    56534
KLM  2020-JAN-12    RET       MATH  TN   TN    56453
```

The above query returns 1st record with enrollement date '2019-AUG-16' but not the other records. I want to get all records from 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that

```
to_date('12'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1), 'MMYYYY')
```

returns (as of 2020) `2019-12-01`, when you need `2019-12-31`. You can work around that by specifying the date as well:

```
to_date('3112'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1), 'DDMMYYYY')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1d33d919c40db877056d725ffb0b9a68)

Another alternative would be to use `TRUNC` to get the first day of this year, and then subtract 1:

```
enrollement_dt <= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR') - 1
```

or even simpler

```
enrollement_dt < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YEAR')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=091e8d238c68dfe41ec9b60fce10d1b2)

Comment: yes '3112' works but wandering why '122019' wouldnt work. looks like it returns 1st Dec 2019. Is there a cleaner way to get the same without specifying month and date?

Comment: Because you didn't specify the day, Oracle assumes you wanted the first of the month, and 31st December is not <= 1st December. See the demo link...

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to get the same without specifying month and date?

Comment: You could use `LAST_DAY` with just the month e.g. `last_day( to_date('12'||(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1), 'MMYYYY'))`

Comment: @JNPW I've added an even cleaner solution and demo